# Java IPAddress library and non-zero CIDRs

Tags: java, cidr

I am using Sean Foley's Java library IPAddress and I'm running into an issue generating IPs from a CIDR. IPAddress does not consider 10.90.6.14/30 a CIDR and addr.isMultiple() returns false.

Our legacy code (Golang) and a couple of online CIDR calculators I've tried return:

10.90.6.12
10.90.6.13
10.90.6.14
10.90.6.15

Can anyone advise me on how to achieve this result using the IPAddress library?

Answer (score 1):

The author of the IPAddress library, Sean Foley, was kind enough to post this answer on the github site (thank you Sean!):

In summary,
10.90.6.14/30 is the same as 10.90.6.14 because the host is not zero. 10.90.6.12/30 is the subnet of 4 addresses because the host is zero. If you want to convert to the subnet, then use toPrefixBlock.

list(new IPAddressString("10.90.6.12/30").getAddress());
list(new IPAddressString("10.90.6.14/30").getAddress().toPrefixBlock());

static void list(IPAddress addr) {
System.out.println(addr + " has count " + addr.getCount());
for(IPAddress addr2 : addr.getIterable()) {
System.out.println(addr2);
}
System.out.println();
}
Output:

10.90.6.12/30 has count 4
10.90.6.12/30
10.90.6.13/30
10.90.6.14/30
10.90.6.15/30

10.90.6.12/30 has count 4
10.90.6.12/30
10.90.6.13/30
10.90.6.14/30
10.90.6.15/30

Comment: you're welcome, @psparago - more details here https://github.com/seancfoley/IPAddress/wiki/Code-Examples-1:-Creating,-Parsing,-Extracting-Address-Subnet-Info#parse-ip-address-string-with-prefix-length-as-subnet-or-ip-address